# Run Spring boot unit tests in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I am working my way through the [Spring boot unit test tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/). [To run the unit tests in Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/performing-tests.html), I have selected the "test" folder in the project window and pressed Cntl+Shift+F10 but nothing happens. The application builds fine, but I do not see a run or a debug caret next to the unit test.

I have checked in the sourcecode [here](https://github.com/ajitgoel/spring-UnitTest-Tutorial). What could I be missing?

**"test" folder in the project window:**

[image]

**No run or a debug caret next to the unit test:**

[image]

**Update 1: 4/23/2022:**
I set the "test" folder as `Test Sources Root`, build the application and I am getting "java: error: release version 16 not supported" error. The Project SDK is set to `jbr-11`, changing it to `openkjdk-18` and rebuilding the application throws 100's of errors.

[image]

Comment: Have your marked the test folder as `Test Sources Root`?

Comment: This is manual how to fix it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/testing.html#create-test-resources-root

Comment: Thanks @JakobF, @Eugene, I am getting a different error after I set the test folder to `Test Sources Root`

Comment: Try to click on `Reload All Gradle projects` in Gradle tool window and download/configure JDK 1.8 for running the project. (File | Project Structure | Project | SDK)

Comment: If you see compilation errors after configuration, open the problem files, hover over the highlighted errors and press Alt + Enter to get a list of suggested fixes. It seems like the project from https://github.com/ajitgoel/spring-UnitTest-Tutorial is not properly uploaded.

Comment: I havent figured out how to run tests in spring boot and intellij ethier.  the only option I can find is a run configuration under JUNIT with "all in project". If I run this, it fails any test using WebTestClient with the error "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient' available"